# New Chrome update kills wmode=transparent

Tags: flash, google-chrome, transparent

The newest version of chrome seems to have killed my transparent backgrounds on my SWF. On a website, I use flash to have a transparent video on top of the elements. However, the background is now black under the newest versions of Chrome.

The question has been asked a few time, but didn't get any answers.

This is my code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="300" height="280" id="vanessa" name="vanessa">
   <param name="movie" value="vanessa.swf" />
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
   <embed id="vanessa"
          name="vanessa"
          src="vanessa.swf"
          width="300"
          height="280"
          wmode="transparent"
   />
</object>
```

And a live preview can be seen on the homepage of this website: http://www.consomachat.com/

Comment: It displays fine for me using Ubuntu 10.04 and the latest Developer Build 18.0.978.0 (Developer Build 115278 Linux) and Chrome 16.0.912.63 beta

Comment: I'm under Windows, like at least 99% of this website clients

Comment: Which version of Chrome? Newest can be deceptive, yeah?

Comment: Eheh, yeah newest at that time. Right now I'm on 16.0.912.63 m. However, it started doing this for a few months, under the dev branch. So it probably started doing this under 14 or 15.

Comment: how does `wmode="opaque"` look with that setup? That may work...also peruse through this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2ca277b12bc29e35&hl=en should give you some things to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2ca277b12bc29e35&hl=en
In reference to my comments above...

I found a solution: this will work with IE,FF,Safari & Chrome! And it shows altervative content.

Step 1) incl. SWFobject to your head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
```

Get the latest version here: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/list

Step 2) incl. the following code into your body

```
<object data="yourfile.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300"     height="280">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
    <param name="quality" value="best">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed src="" quality="high" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="280"></embed>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="movie" value="yourfile.swf" />

        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="yourfile.swf" width="300" height="280">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <p>alternative content</p>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

To clarify:
What seems to be the most important is to include `wmode="transparent` to the `<embed src`

```
<embed src="" quality="high" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="280"></embed>
```

Comment: Umm, seems to work here, I'm away from home for the holidays, I will ask my client if it still does the same thing at his place. Thanks for  the help, I'll keep you updated and approve your answer if everything is alright!

Comment: Cool, good luck! Happy Holidays! Did you change much other than adding the <embed> ? Just curious. Thanks

Comment: Fixed everything, thanks again! Didn't change much, I'm not too sure what I changed, since I copy pasted most of your code.

Answer (score 3):

I used TryTryAgain's answer, and it turns out the part that fixed it for me is adding type to the initial object tag.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="...">
</object>
```